# Android: Não persiste o dado no MySQL

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Boa Tarde,

Com o código abaixo consigo uma mensagem de sucesso ao executar o método, mas o dado não consta na tabela ao validar se foi persistido no banco de dados (MySQL).

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

EditText edtDocumento, edtNome, edtProfissao;
Button btnCadastrar;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

RequestQueue request;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    btnCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);
    edtDocumento = findViewById(R.id.edtDocumento);
    edtNome = findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
    edtProfissao = findViewById(R.id.edtProfissao);

    request  = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            carregarWebService();


        }
    });

}

private void carregarWebService() {

    String url = "http://192.168.0.1/exemploBDRemota/wsJSONRegistro.php?documento=" + edtDocumento.getText().toString() +
            "&nome=" + edtNome.getText().toString() + "&profissao=" + edtProfissao.getText().toString();

    url = url.replace(" ","%20");


    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Registrado com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    edtDocumento.setText("");
    edtNome.setText("");
    edtProfissao.setText("");

}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


    //progressDialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Falha ao registrar. " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
}
}
```

---

PHP

```
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "db_usuario";
$username_localhost = "root";
$senha_localhost = "";

$json = array();

if(isset($_GET["documento"]) && isset($GET["nome"]) && isset($GET["profissao"])){

    $documento = $GET['documento'];
    $nome = $GET['nome'];
    $profissao = $GET['profissao'];

    $conexao = mysqli_connect ($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $senha_localhost, $database_localhost);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO usuario(documento, nome, profissao) VALUES ('{$documento}','{$nome}','{$profissao}')";
    $resultado_insert = mysqli_query($conexao, $insert);


    if($resultado_insert){

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE documento = '{$documento}'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta);


        if($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $json['usuario'][] = $registro;
        }

        mysqli_close($conexao);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }

    else{
        $resulta["documento"] = 0;
        $resulta["nome"] = 'Nao Registrado';
        $resulta["profissao"] = 'Nao Registrada';   
        $json['usuario'][] = $resulta;
        echo json_encode($json);    

    }
}
else{
    $resulta["documento"] = 0;
    $resulta["nome"] = 'WS Nao Retorna';
    $resulta["profissao"] = 'WS Nao Retorna';

    $json['usuario'][] = $resulta;
    echo json_encode($json);    
}
```

Comment: O onResponse só retorna que houve uma resposta OK do servidor.  Faça isso `mysqli_query($conexao, $insert) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));` e veja se aparece algum erro!

Comment: Já considerou implementar o webservice com Laravel e i5Repository?